# Add element to jQuery selection

Tags: jquery

Given this:

```
var $parent=$('.list');
var $children=$parent.find('li');

//Later on
$parent.append($newLI);//$newLI is a new <li> element
$children=$parent.find('li');//Refresh the jQuery collection
```

Is there a better way of writing the last line that refreshes the jQuery collection?
There must be.

Thank you.

Comment: So you want `$children` to be a live list, basically?

Comment: I just need it to "refresh" once, I don't need it to be live after that refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$children = $children.add($newLI);
```

[add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) docs:

> Description: Add elements to the set of matched elements.

Comment: @Rob W. That's not correct _"The following will not save the added elements, because the .add() method creates a new set and leaves the original set unchanged."_

Comment: I tried that before posting and it didn't work. I'll give it another shot.

Comment: @Francisc. Did you save the result as I did?

Comment: No. That's what I wanted to try. Thought `.add()` would change the collection.

Comment: @Francisc. =). Sorry missed the _"Thought"_ key word in the last comment... =) cheers!

Comment: Waiting for SO to allow me to mark the answer as correct. `3 mins`

Answer (score -1):

Could try

```
  $parent.append($newLI);
   $children=$children.add( $newLI);
```

Comment: That's not correct _"The following will not save the added elements, because the .add() method creates a new set and leaves the original set unchanged."_

Comment: I did, I think `.add()` doesn't change the $children collection unless you re-assign it to itself like gdoron showed.

Comment: @charlietfl. Never used `add()` before at all... **=)**